# Spotfire Load on Demand for External Table

Tags: spotfire

Suppose I have two tables, TableA(embedded data), TableB(external data).

Scenario 1:
TableB is set On-Demand based on the markings from TableA. When you mark something from TableA, it take some "n" seconds to populate the data in TableB.  On-Demand setting on external table is like screenshot named LOD.png[image]

Scenario 2:
On-Demand settings have not been induced on TableB(please note TableB still is External). There has been a relationship created between TableA and TableB. TableB is now limited based on marking from TableA by the option"Limit data using Markings".screenshot named ss2[image]

Questions:
1. Which scenario fetches data quicker.
2. From the debug log, the query passed in both the scenario is the same.Does that mean both scenarios are same or are they different?

Answer (score 1):

Scenario 1 is good if Table B is really large, or records take a long time to fetch from the database. In this case, Table B is only returning rows that are based on what you marked in Table A. This means that the number of rows could be significantly less, but this also means that every time the marking changes, those rows have to be fetched at that time. If the database takes a long time, this can become frustrating. On the flip side, if the database is really fast and you are limiting rows down enough, this can be almost seamless. At the end of the day, you are pulling this data into memory after the query runs, so all Spotfire functionality is available.

Scenario 2 is good if calculations are highly complex and need to take advantage of the power of the external DB to perform. This means that any change to the report, a change of visualization etc., will require a new query to be sent to the external data source resulting in a new table of aggregated data. This means that no changes to a visualization using an in-db data table can be made when you are not connected to the external data source. Please note, there is functionality in Spotfire that is available to in memory data like data on demand that is not available to external data.

I personally like to keep data close to Spotfire to take advantage of all Spotfire functionality, but I cannot tell you exactly which is the correct method in your case. Perhaps these TIBCO links on the difference between in memory data and external data can help:

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/data/data_overview.htm
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/data/data_working_with_in-database_data.htm

Comment: Hello Mark,

Thanks a ton for your detailed explanation on this. I however have one question , in Scenario 2(Table B) is still an external why would the data be in memory when Table B is "External Data"? Table B does not have On-Demand settings implemented though

Comment: Oh I missed that. Adding Clarification.